# How is DONDA SPORTS associated with antisemitism?

Tags: media

[Aaron Donald and Jaylen Brown](https://www.espn.com/nba/story/_/id/34878645/celtics-jaylen-brown-rams-aaron-donald-leaving-donda-sports) recently left DONDA SPORTS due to antisemitic remarks made by founder Ye (fka Kanye West).

What were these comments? Why are athletes turning away from DONDA SPORTS as a result of these comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Donda Sports is an [agency ... founded ... by Ye (Kanye West) and Justin Laboy](https://www.sbnation.com/2022/10/26/23424460/what-is-donda-sports-a-debrief-on-kanyes-marketing-agency-that-lost-aaron-donald-and-jaylen-brown), and as such is linked to Ye as the co-owner and co-founder.  (Note: Ye is the current preferred name of the person who used to be known as Kanye West.)

Both players stated that they left the agency due to the anti-semitic remarks made by Ye (see the letters reprinted in the article above). As to *exactly* why they made that choice, you'd have to ask them, any specific reason would be speculation.